# APA reference format with numbers

Tags: numbering, apa-style

I was told by my editor that I need to write the references of my article in APA format. So I went ahead and used the `apacite` package with `\usepackage{apacite}` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`.

Now, the editor got back to me and told me they actually want APA style, but instead of having citations in the form `(Author, year)`, they want them in the form `[number]`.

Is there any setting I can play with to get `apacite` to behave like this?

Here is an example of how I would need things, as you can see references are numbered:

[image: References]

Comment: This is doable with `biblatex`: [APA bibliography style with numbers](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/373336).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How did you solve this? [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/)